# Evaluating a trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

I got a math clock as a gift last year. It has various complicated expressions for each hour. I have been able to verify most of them, but I am stuck on an attempt to verify that $$79\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}-\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)=3.$$

I applied an angle difference identity for tangent to get:
$$
79\cdot\frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)-\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)}{1+\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\cdot\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)}.
$$

Then I calculated that $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}$ and substituted to get:
$$
79\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}-\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)}{1+\left(\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdot\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)}.
$$

I am left with evaluating $\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)$. I am aware of various identities involving $\pi$ and arctangents of of various unit fractions, but the thing that is stymying my efforts is how to deal with $\frac{5}{2}$ as a product inside the tangent function. Is there some arcane tangent identity such as $\tan(\alpha\beta)=??$ for arbitrary angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$? I have searched online for a bit and have come up empty.

Hints only please with how to proceed with my attempt or another strategy to evaluate.

UPDATE: Following the hint I got from Simple Art, I was able to show that
$$
\tan\left(\frac{5}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)=\frac{2879\sqrt{2}}{6250+3353\sqrt{2}}.
$$

This now leaves me with the task of showing that
$$
79\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{2879\sqrt{2}}{6250+3353\sqrt{2}}}{1+\left(\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{2879\sqrt{2}}{6250+3353\sqrt{2}}\right)}=3.
$$

Should be a piece of cake from here. HA!

UPDATE 2:
I needed to use a different identity for evaluating $\tan(\pi/8)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$ rather than $\tan(\pi/8)=\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}$. With this final change and a little bit of algebra, it resolves itself quite nicely.

Comment: Half angle formula followed by Chebyshev polynomials for $\tan(5\phi)$ in terms of $\tan(\phi)$

Comment: That is just what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: Nice, love the simple answer.  Almost like art.